# Problems combining (union) Multipolygons in geodjango

Tags: django, postgis, geodjango, geos

I'm using geodjango and postgis (1.x),
What is the best way to combine (union) a list of multipolygons.

in what i assume is rather inefficient i'm looping trough like this

```
combined = multipolygon
for item in items:
    combined = combined.union(item.geom)  #geom is a multipolygon
```

Usually this works fine, but often i'm getting the error Error encountered checking Geometry returned from GEOS C function "GEOSUnion_r".

Here is the geo json version of the item the error is thrown on if it helps

```
{ "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": 
[ [ [ [ -80.077576, 26.572225 ], 
      [ -80.037729, 26.571180 ], 
      [ -80.080279, 26.273744 ], 
      [ -80.147464, 26.310066 ], 
      [ -80.152851, 26.455851 ], 
      [ -80.138560, 26.538013 ], 
      [ -80.077576, 26.572225 ] 
] ] ] 
}
```

does anyone have anyideas? the end goal is to take find all the locations (another table) which fall within this list of n polygons (using coordinates__within=combined_area)

Also, the polygons show up fine on the maps in the geodjango admin.

Answer (score 4):

You can always use [Union](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.Union) aggregate method. That should be a bit more efficient because everything is computed on the database level which means you don't have to loop over things in Python.

```
combined_area = FooModel.objects.filter(...).aggregate(area=Union('geom'))['area']
final = BarModel.objects.filter(coordinates__within=combined_area)
```

Comment: i'll try this in a little bit, thanks for the tip.  Any idea why i would be getting that " Error encountered checking Geometry returned from GEOS C function "GEOSUnion_r". when doing it the other way?

Comment: the only thing I can think of is that the geom column is null or empty

Comment: although cleaner, that method is returning null when encountering the problem geometries.   

The geometries aren't empty, but trying to run the queries directly in postgres i get 
NOTICE:  TopologyException: found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING ...   Also it only seems to affect certain combinations of geometries


and, in case its relevant 
POSTGIS="1.5.3" GEOS="3.3.8-CAPI-1.7.8" PROJ="Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009" LIBXML="2.7.6" USE_STATS

Comment: That is very weird. At least you can narrow down that Django is not an issue and that something is happening in postgres.

Comment: Well, some more digging and i found this link

http://linfiniti.com/2010/07/cleaning-geometries-inside-postgis/

there is a function in here which will clean up bad geometries.  For the time being I will, routinely run something like
 
update mytable set  geom = cleangeometry(geom)  where id in (select id  from mytable where st_isvalid(geom) = false);

I'm not particularly thrilled with this, but it should help things from getting too far off.